# What exactly is a funnel seek test?

Tags: hard-drive

What, exactly, is a hard-drive funnel seek test?  From the name I understand that it's a test that a hard-drive's read-write-heads seek properly, but what does "funnel" mean?  Is it moving the heads in a particular physical pattern?

Comment: I googled "funnel seek test" and the first match gave me the answer. Why did you not do the same?

Comment: @AFH D'oh!  I saw the answer page, but stopped reading when I got to "Is the hard drive toast?", *assuming* that the answer wouldn't explain what it was.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found some info on a [PC hardware forum](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=63394) and it makes sense. The name funnel probably has to do with the pattern formed by the accessed sectors (from the inner to the outer sectors and back to inner again).

> Funnel Seek (aka Butterfly Seek) - tests track zero first, and then steps out to test the outermost track next. It then steps back and tests track one and steps out to test the next-to-outermost track. This operation continues until the whole disk has been tested. The butterfly seek is the most rigorous seek test.